# Spring Security does not allow js to load

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I haven't worked with Spring Security before, so I'm new here.

I have a page that loads js, I have set up access for everyone to the package with js, but it still does not skip

```java
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/welcome").setViewName("welcome");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("welcome");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/admin").setViewName("admin");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/registration").setViewName("registration");
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }

}
```

This is the Spring Security configuration file

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/welcome", "/registration", "/admin", "/resources/**", "/add", "/listOfUsers" ).permitAll()

                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new MyUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

The controller file

```java
@RestController
public class BackendController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


  
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public void processFormData(@RequestBody String jsonUser) throws JsonProcessingException {
        User user = jsonStringToUser(jsonUser);  // Получаю объект User из json
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        System.out.println(user);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
   
    @GetMapping("/listOfUsers")
    public String listOfUsers() throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        return usersToJson(users);  
    }
   
    private User jsonStringToUser(String jsonUser) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        User user = objectMapper.readValue(jsonUser, User.class);
        return user;
    }
   
    private String usersToJson(List<User> users) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonUsers = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(users);
        return jsonUsers;
    }
}
```

js file

```java
function submitForm() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var secondName = document.getElementById("secondName").value;
    var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var role;
    if (document.getElementById('role_student').checked) {
        role = document.getElementById('role_student').value;
    }
    else{
        role = document.getElementById('role_teacher').value;
    }


    fetch('/add', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

        body: JSON.stringify({firstName: firstName, secondName: secondName, phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                                email: email, username: username, password: password, role: role})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

        console.log(data);

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });

}

async function getListOfUsers(){
    let response = await fetch("/listOfUsers");
    let users = await response.json();
    let list = document.querySelector('.listOfUsers');

    for(key in users){
        list.innerHTML += `
            <tr>
                <th>${users[key].firstName}</th>
                <th>${users[key].secondName}</th>
                <th>${users[key].phoneNumber}</th>
                <th>${users[key].email}</th>
                <th>${users[key].username}</th>
                <th>${users[key].password}</th>
                <th>${users[key].role}</th>
             </tr>
        `;
    }

}

getListOfUsers();
```

if i poison the request using postman to the REST-controller address, then everything works fine, but if you open the page through the browser, then js simply gives the status 302 and does not load

Comment: o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /static/js/admin.js

 o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

 o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/js/admin.js?continue to session

o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8080/login

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login

Comment: omg, thank you, i just change ```.requestMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()``` in ```.requestMatchers("/static/js/**").permitAll()``` .

my js files in ```/resources/static/js```, why  /resources/** didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mapped the static content to `/static`, see :

> **addResourceHandler**
>
> `public ResourceHandlerRegistration addResourceHandler(String... pathPatterns)`
>
> Add a resource handler to serve static resources. The handler is invoked for requests that match one of the specified URL path patterns.

So you have to use this URL path within your Spring Security configuration.